# Where should I start for a flowchart drawing application in Java

Tags: java, frameworks, visio, flowchart

I want to build a desktop application using Java. The purpose will be drawing a kind of flowchart so I will have some objects in a palette and I will drag and drop the objects to a workspace. Then the workspace will generate some xml according to the objects. You can think that, in result I will have a Microsoft Visio like application but a very simplified version and also capable of generating some xml representation of the drawn flowchart.

Where should I start for such an application? Which libraries/frameworks can I use?

Thanks..

Comment: It is off topic..  Did you check source code of argouml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/) to do something similar.  It hasn't had any activity since 2011 but still works in Java 8.

You could also try JavaFX.